# How do I iterate over cin line by line in C++?

Tags: c++, string, line-processing

I want to iterate over `std::cin`, line by line, addressing each line as a `std::string`.  Which is better:

```
string line;
while (getline(cin, line))
{
    // process line
}
```

or

```
for (string line; getline(cin, line); )
{
    // process line
}
```

?  What is the normal way to do this?

Answer (score 83):

Since UncleBen brought up his LineInputIterator, I thought I'd add a couple more alternative methods. First up, a really simple class that acts as a string proxy:

```
class line {
    std::string data;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) {
        std::getline(is, l.data);
        return is;
    }
    operator std::string() const { return data; }    
};
```

With this, you'd still read using a normal istream_iterator. For example, to read all the lines in a file into a vector of strings, you could use something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<line>(std::cin), 
          std::istream_iterator<line>(),
          std::back_inserter(lines));
```

The crucial point is that when you're *reading* something, you specify a line -- but otherwise, you just have strings.

Another possibility uses a part of the standard library most people barely even know exists, not to mention being of much real use. When you read a string using operator>>, the stream returns a string of characters up to whatever that stream's locale says is a white space character. Especially if you're doing a lot of work that's all line-oriented, it can be convenient to create a locale with a ctype facet that only classifies new-line as white-space:

```
struct line_reader: std::ctype<char> {
    line_reader(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}
    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());

        rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

To use this, you imbue the stream you're going to read from with a locale using that facet, then just read strings normally, and operator>> for a string always reads a whole line. For example, if we wanted to read in lines, and write out unique lines in sorted order, we could use code like this:

```
int main() {
    std::set<std::string> lines;

    // Tell the stream to use our facet, so only '\n' is treated as a space.
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new line_reader()));

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), 
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), 
        std::inserter(lines, lines.end()));

    std::copy(lines.begin(), lines.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that this affects all input from the stream. Using this pretty much rules out mixing line-oriented input with other input (e.g. reading a number from the stream using `stream>>my_integer` would normally fail).

Comment: I know there was a way to specify on which character stop... well I still kind of hope there is a simpler way... I wonder how the language even become so gross, it makes me sad sometimes. +1 for the proxy. Easy to write, easy to use, and much more flexible.

Comment: Guys, his name is cppLearner.  Really.

Comment: this much-referenced example with line doesn't compile for me unless I make that `operator std::string()` **const** : https://ideone.com/xcJ4Z vs https://ideone.com/YY8cQ

Comment: @Cubbi: Hmm...I'm not sure how that got missed all this time, but I've fixed it.

Comment: The facet is a really neat trick. I stole it for a different purpose just to see if it would work, and it did! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439291/parsing-a-csv-file-consisting-numbers-with-characters-in-between-c/46439752#46439752

Answer (score 8):

What I have (written as an exercise, but perhaps turns out useful one day), is LineInputIterator:

```
#ifndef UB_LINEINPUT_ITERATOR_H
#define UB_LINEINPUT_ITERATOR_H

#include <iterator>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

namespace ub {

template <class StringT = std::string>
class LineInputIterator :
    public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, StringT, std::ptrdiff_t, const StringT*, const StringT&>
{
public:
    typedef typename StringT::value_type char_type;
    typedef typename StringT::traits_type traits_type;
    typedef std::basic_istream<char_type, traits_type> istream_type;

    LineInputIterator(): is(0) {}
    LineInputIterator(istream_type& is): is(&is) {}
    const StringT& operator*() const { return value; }
    const StringT* operator->() const { return &value; }
    LineInputIterator<StringT>& operator++()
    {
        assert(is != NULL);
        if (is && !getline(*is, value)) {
            is = NULL;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    LineInputIterator<StringT> operator++(int)
    {
        LineInputIterator<StringT> prev(*this);
        ++*this;
        return prev;
    }
    bool operator!=(const LineInputIterator<StringT>& other) const
    {
        return is != other.is;
    }
    bool operator==(const LineInputIterator<StringT>& other) const
    {
        return !(*this != other);
    }
private:
    istream_type* is;
    StringT value;
};

} // end ub
#endif
```

So your loop could be replaced with an algorithm (another recommended practice in C++):

```
for_each(LineInputIterator<>(cin), LineInputIterator<>(), do_stuff);
```

Perhaps a common task is to store every line in a container:

```
vector<string> lines((LineInputIterator<>(stream)), LineInputIterator<>());
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one.

Both do the same, but the first one is much more readable, plus you get to keep the string variable after the loop is done (in the 2nd option, its enclosed in the for loop scope)

Comment: Isn't it a good thing to keep the line in the for scope?  Outside the scope it's not much use, since it will end up holding the value of the last line or something?

Comment: @cppLearner: Good point, but perhaps you should put this in a function of its own, so the temporarily used string goes out of scope anyway.

Comment: You can always use bare braces, in the event that there's a good reason to limit the scope of the string, but also a good reason that some other bit of code before and/or after the loop should be in the same function. I don't think limiting scope should determine whether to use "for" or "while", what should determine it is whether you're waiting for something to be false (while), or traversing something that's conceptually a range (for). Obviously the difference between the two is a fuzzy boundary. They're logically equivalent, it's just about how you conceive of the loop.

Comment: By "bare braces", I mean `{ string line; while (getline(cin,line)) { // process line } } // more code goes here`.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the while statement.

See Chapter 16.2 (specifically pages 374 and 375) of Code Complete 2 by Steve McConell.

To quote:

> **Don't use a for loop when a while loop is more appropriate.** A common abuse of the flexible for loop structure in C++, C# and Java is haphazardly cramming the contents of a while loop into a for loop header.

.

> **C++ Example of a while loop abusively Crammed into a for Loop Header**

```
for (inputFile.MoveToStart(), recordCount = 0; !inputFile.EndOfFile(); recordCount++) {
    inputFile.GetRecord();
}
```

> **C++ Example of appropriate use of a while loop**

```
inputFile.MoveToStart();
recordCount = 0;
while (!InputFile.EndOfFile()) {
    inputFile.getRecord();
    recordCount++;
}
```

I've omitted some parts in the middle but hopefully that gives you a good idea.

Comment: As usual, Steve has a good idea, but poor execution. First of all, this use of the for loop isn't particularly abusive. Second, and more importantly, both versions (using the for or the while) display an anti-pattern, using EndOfFile() as the loop exit condition, which is pretty guaranteed to give incorrect results.

Comment: Agree with the for(;;) abuse principle. But I disagree with the example being abuse. And like Jerry putting the EndOfFile() test there is a no-no. Shouts Ant-Pattern. Though I would probably move recordCount into the body and move GetRecord() into the for(;;)

Comment: @Martin, he provides another example of the `for` which he considers slightly better that which is what you describe

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Jerry Coffin's answer. I wanted to show c++20's `std::ranges::istream_view`. I also added a line number to the class. I did this on godbolt, so I could see what happened. This version of the line class still works with `std::input_iterator`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/basic_istream_view

https://www.godbolt.org/z/94Khjz

```cpp
class line {
    std::string data{};
    std::intmax_t line_number{-1};
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) {
        std::getline(is, l.data);
        ++l.line_number;
        return is;
    }
    explicit operator std::string() const { return data; }
    explicit operator std::string_view() const noexcept { return data; }
    constexpr explicit operator std::intmax_t() const noexcept { return line_number; }    
};
int main()
{
    std::string l("a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng");
    std::stringstream ss(l);
    for(const auto & x : std::ranges::istream_view<line>(ss))
    {
        std::cout << std::intmax_t(x) << " " << std::string_view(x) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

prints out:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
5 f
6 g
```