# Can you tell iostreams which characters to treat as whitespace?

Tags: c++, string, iostream

So that you could do something like this, for instance:

```
std::string a("01:22:42.18");
std::stringstream ss(a);
int h, m, s, f;
ss >> h >> m >> s >> f;
```

Which normally requires the string to be formatted `"01 22 42 18"`.
Can you modify the current locale directly to do this?

Comment: I guess you can't do it. Interesting question though +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) and [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/).  You might* be able to do something like this:

```
int h, m, s, f;
sscanf(a.c_str(), "%d:%d:%d.%d", &h, &m, &s, &f);
```

* Caveat: It's been a while for me and C++

Comment: Right, using C's `scanf` instead of C++'s `istream::operator>>` is definitely much easier.  You may have meant `sscanf(a.c_str(), "%d:%d:%d.%d", &h, &m, &s, &f) == 4` though.

Comment: Thanks, that's a practical solution.

Comment: @ephemient Ya, that's the one.  Like I said, it's been a while since I've touched any C/C++ @henle If that's your solution, then mark it as the answer mate ;)

Comment: Ok, Justin, since you're asking nicely, but the other suggestions were good as well! ;)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can change the default delimiter without creating a new locale, but that seems hackish. What you can use do is use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) with a third parameter specifying the delimiter character or you could read the delimiters and not do anything with them (e.g. ss >> h >> d >> m >> d >> s >> d >> f).

You could also write your own parsing class that handles splitting strings for you. Or better yet, use [boost::split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3483755) from Boost's [String Algorithms Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/string_algo.html).

Comment: the annoying thing with `boost::split` and `getline` is that you have to split up the strings and then feed them back into a stream to get the integers

Comment: You can use `boost::split` to transform the `std::string` into a `std::vector<std::string>`, then use `std::transform` with `boost::lexical_cast` to transform the `std::vector<std::string>` into a `std::vector<unsigned int>`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by creating a locale with a ctype facet classifying `:` as whitespace.

[Jerry Coffin explains how you can specify whitespace characters in this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c/1567703#1567703).

Comment: Thank you, that would be the literal answer to my question! Though I'm trying to figure out if you can just do an
rc[':'] = std::ctype_base::space;
without creating a whole new locale ...

Comment: Unfortunately, since ios_base classifies characters as whitespace based on the imbued locale, I don't think there are any other options. Firas's suggestion of boost::split (or, alternatively, boost::tokenizer) is probably your next best bet.

Answer (score 2):

```
char c;
if (!(ss >> h >> c) || c != ':') return;
if (!(ss >> m >> c) || c != ':') return;
if (!(ss >> s >> c) || c != '.') return;
if (!(ss >> f) || ss >> c) return;
```