# Iterating over lines in a string?

Tags: c++, string, boost

I am trying to do something like this:

```
BOOST_FOREACH (const std::string& line, allLinesOf(someFileLoadedIntoString))
{
   ...
}
```

I wonder how to implement the allLinesOf function? Thanks!

UPDATE: Thanks for the answers. Sorry but I forgot to mention one important detail: in my case the newlines are \r\n.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a C++ iterator that can iterate over a file line by line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291802/is-there-a-c-iterator-that-can-iterate-over-a-file-line-by-line) (though, Jerry's answer to [How do I iterate over `cin` line by line in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c) is better than that exact duplicate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line)) {
    // Ohai!
}
```

Comment: Will it work with "\r\n" newlines? The string is loaded from a text file on Windows.

Comment: @Alex: You can specify a separator, from memory, and in addition, I believe that the MSVC STL automatically converts "\r\n" to "\n" when loading in text mode.

Comment: The I/O Streams library performs newline translation, so when you open a file stream in text mode, it will automatically translate the platform line ending (which may be `\r\n` or something else) into the C++ line ending (`\n`).

Answer (score 2):

Um, you can write a custom iterator for std::string that would iterate over string segments separated by newlines and pass a std::pair of such iterators to BOOST_FOREACH

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm) with `\n` token to iterate over lines.

Comment: Would it be possible to pack it into one allLinesOf function?

Comment: Might not be a good idea in some cases. Look here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html

Comment: Or BOOST_FOREACH in conjunction with boost::split :)

Comment: @Aamir, `\n` in not necessarily is `0x0A`. The Standard guarantees that `\n` is the line end independently of the OS used.