# Counting the tokens when you tokenize the string in C++?

Tags: c++, token, tokenize

Java has this easy method to count the tokens that you tokenize:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    String str =
        "This is/some text/that I am/parsing/using StringTokenizer/.";

    StringTokenizer strTok =
        new StringTokenizer(str, "/", false);

    System.out.println("Count...");
    System.out.println(strTok.countTokens());
}
}



Output:Count...6
```

Is there any easy way to do in C++?

Comment: The question to you is `how are you tokenizing the string in C++?` Are you using `strtok`, `boost::Tokenizer`, your own code ...?

Comment: I've written [this function](http://pastebin.com/fAVM3C4C) last week.

Comment: You have to use `boost` from C++ 11. The old C++ standard doesn't have the API to do it. You have to code it yourself if you are using the old standard.

Comment: @user3437460 d'oh, what? "You have to use boost from C++ 11. " - that's not even meaningful, Boost is not part of C++11. Also, "have to"? Why? There are plenty of things you can use in C++03. Also, why would OP have to stay away from C++11?

Comment: PaulMcKenzie- I am using strtok, boost::Tokenizer

Comment: Well, `boost::Tokenizer` has a `begin` and `end` function at the very least. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `std::istringstream`class along with function `std::getline`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "This is/some text/that I am/parsing/using StringTokenizer/.";

    std::istringstream is( s );

    size_t count = 0;

    std::string line;

    while ( std::getline( is, line, '/' ) ) ++count;

    std::cout << "There are " << count << " tokens" << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
There are 6 tokens
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "This is/some text/that I am/parsing/using StringTokenizer/.";

    std::istringstream is( s );

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string line;

    while ( std::getline( is, line, '/' ) ) v.push_back( line );

    std::cout << "There are " << v.size() << " tokens" << std::endl;
}
```

To build again the string from the vector you could use for example the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "This is/some text/that I am/parsing/using StringTokenizer/.";

    std::istringstream is( s );

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string line;

    while ( std::getline( is, line, '/' ) ) v.push_back( line );

    std::cout << "There are " << v.size() << " tokens" << std::endl;

    std::string s1;

    bool first = true;
    for ( const std::string &t : v )
    {
        if ( first ) first = false;
        else s1 += '/';

        s1 += t;
    }

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
}
```

Or you could use standard algorithm `std::replace` declared in header `<algorithm>` to replace one delimeter to another in the original string.

If your compiler does not support the range based for loop then you can write instead

```
    for ( std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        if ( i != 0 ) s1 += '/';

        s1 += v[i];
    }
```

Comment: Vlad From Moscow you always have an intelligent approach in C++! Thanks brother. Let me implement the codes as quick as possible

Comment: Vlad From Moscow- I have other question that is related to this question. How possibly put together back all those tokens that you already parsed? With maybe a different delimeter? For instance instead of space, we use comma? does it make sense?

Comment: Vlad from Moscow- Thanks bud. I got another problem when I implemented these codes into mine. I use C++98 so It gives error on the for loop that you posted. for(const std::string &t:v)

Comment: Vlad from Moscow- you codes are brilliant...I really envy that I could code like that. You use really powerful C++. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
std::vector<std::string> v(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), {});

std::cout << "Count..." << v.size() << "\n";
```

This will of course tokenize at spaces, not at arbitrary separators. To split on arbitary separators, we need `std::getline`, but now we don't have an easy `istream_iterator`. Thankfully, this is a [solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291802/is-there-a-c-iterator-that-can-iterate-over-a-file-line-by-line). So we write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace detail 
{
    template <char Sep = '\n'>
    class Line : public std::string 
    { 
        friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, Line & line)
        {   
            return std::getline(is, line, Sep);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v(std::istream_iterator<detail::Line<'/'>>(std::cin), {});
    std::cout << "Count..." << v.size() << "\n";
    for (auto const & s : v) std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

If you want to tokenize an existing string rather than the standard input, use a string stream, i.e. replace `std::cin` with `iss`, where we have:

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream iss(my_input_string);
```