# istream stop at \n

Tags: c++, newline, istream

Is there any way of telling istream to keep going until it hits \n instead of normal white space and with out the use of getline and also keeping any format options in the stream?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a facet.  Jerry Coffin presented a great example of how to do this in an answer to another question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c/1567703#1567703

Comment: Why do you not want to use `std::getline()`?

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with `std::getline()`? Anyway, how about writing your own function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<class In, class Out, class T>
Out copy_until(In first, In last, Out res, const T& val)
{
    while( first != last && *first != val ) *res++ = *first++;
    return res;
}

// ...    
std::string line;
copy_until(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin),
           std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
           std::back_inserter(line), '\n');
std::cout << line << std::endl;
```

The function will consume the newline, but won't place it in the output.