# Reading lines from a file using std:: istream_iterator. Who?

Tags: c++, stl, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I iterate over cin line by line in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c)

I need to read all lines from a file:

```
std::ifstream file("...");
std::vector<std::string> svec(
   (std::istream_iterator<std::string>(file)),
   (std::istream_iterator<std::string>()),
);
```

but it is read as words.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I iterate over cin line by line in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c) (Ok, it's not an _exact_ duplicate, but the answers there should all apply to this question as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the input methods for `std::string` will read until a space character is found, then terminate.

Have you tried using `std::getline` inside a loop?

Check out the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.4).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I know about std::getline().
But the question is more out of curiosity.
So, any way can not read the file line by line with iterators?