# Is there a way i can control the inputs in order to stop the user from typing blank spaces?

Tags: c++

I need to store some user info in arrays so i wrote a function to validate that info, but since c++ stores the info util it reads a blank space and it stores what ever is after the space in the next list

```
int valString(string x)
{
    char c;
    bool bandera = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        c = x.at(i);
        if ((isalpha(c) == 0) || c == ' ') {
            cout << "ERROR el caracter >>>" << c << " <<< es INVALIDO" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    bandera = true;
    if (bandera == true) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: int valString(string x)
{
    char c;
    bool bandera=false;
    for(int i=0; i<x.size(); i++)
    {
                c = x.at(i);
                if (( isalpha(c)==0 ) || c == ' ' )
                {
                    cout<<"ERROR el caracter >>>"<<c<<" <<< es INVALIDO"<<endl;
                    system("pause");
                    return 0;
                }
    }
    bandera=true;
    if (bandera == true)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

Comment: "_but since c++ stores the info util it reads a blank space and it stores what ever is after the space in the next list_" - what? C++ will just do what you tell it to do. Please make a [mre].

Comment: What do you think the lines `bandera = true; if (bandera = true)` will do? If you say `bandera = true` and then immediately test the value, it will **always** be true, so you might as well replace those four lines of code with one `erturn 1;` line. It's important to understand the code you're writing.

Comment: I suspect you are asking the wrong question for your problem, akin to an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You probably should have asked [Why does space always terminate a string when read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947194)