# boost regex tokenizer and newline

Tags: c++, regex, boost, tokenize

I'm currently trying to split up a text file into a vector of strings whenever a newline is encountered. Previously I have used boost tokenizer to do this with other delimiter characters but when I use the newline '\n' it throws an exception at runtime:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::escaped_list_error'
  what():  unknown escape sequence
Aborted
```

Here's the code:

```
std::vector<std::string> parse_lines(const std::string& input_str){
    using namespace boost;
    std::vector<std::string> parsed;
    tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> > tk(input_str, escaped_list_separator<char>('\n'));
    for (tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> >::iterator i(tk3.begin());
                i != tk.end(); ++i) 
    {
       parsed.push_back(*i);
    }
    return parsed;
}
```

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AJG85 this produces the following error `textPanel.cpp:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’
textPanel.cpp:33: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘boost::escaped_list_separator<Char, Traits>::escaped_list_separator(Char, Char, Char) [with Char = char, Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
`

Comment: Right it's been awhile since I used `boost::tokenizer` let me dust off the telecom socket server and see how I did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`escaped_list_separator`'s constructor expects the escape character, then the delimiter character, then the quote character. By using a newline as your escape character, its treating the first character in every line in your input as part of an escape sequence. Try this instead.

`escaped_list_separator<char>('\\', '\n')`

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tokenizer/escaped_list_separator.htm

Answer (score 3):

Given that the separator you want is already supported directly by the standard library, I think I'd skip using regexes for this at all, and use what's already present in the standard library:

```
std::vector<std::string> parse_lines(std::string const &input_string) { 
    std::istringstream buffer(input_string);
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(buffer, line))
        ret.push_back(line);
    return ret;
}
```

Once you deal with the problem by treating the string as a stream and read lines from there, you have quite a few options about the details of how you go from there. Just for a couple of examples, you might want to use use the line proxy and/or LineInputIterator classes that @UncleBens and I posted in response to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c/1567703).

Answer (score 1):

This might work better.

```
boost::char_separator<char> sep("\n");
boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(text, sep);
```

Edit: Alternately you can use `std::find` and make your own splitter loop.