# Using std::copy - error C2679: can't find correct binary '=' operator

Tags: c++, copy, compiler-errors, iostream

I am trying to use a solution from this question:

- [How do I iterate over cin line by line in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c/1567703#1567703)

**The error message**

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2144): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Line' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

(and a bunch of template trace data after this)

I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express.

**The code**

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>

class Line
{
  std::string data;

public:
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inputStream, Line& line)
  {
    std::getline(inputStream, line.data);
    return inputStream;
  }

  operator std::string()
  {
    return data;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::fstream file("filename.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
  std::vector<std::string> lines;

  // error is in one of these lines
  std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<Line>(file),
    std::istream_iterator<Line>(),
    std::back_inserter(lines));
}
```

Comment: And a similar error out of (I think) GCC: http://codepad.org/G3Chty9K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is correct version that compiles fine :

```
class Line
{
    std::string data;

    public:
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inputStream, Line& line)
        {
            std::getline(inputStream, line.data);
            return inputStream;
        }

        operator std::string() const
        {
            return data;
        }
};
```

The conversion operator needs to be `const`.

Answer (score 2):

I changed:

```
  operator std::string()
```

To

```
operator std::string() const
```

and it compiled fine.