# C++ vector::push_back using default copy constructor

Tags: c++, vector, copy, copy-constructor

I have a class (Uniform) that has a constructor with 2 parameters, and a default copy constructor (it only contains int, floats, a std::vector and a std::map). I created a

```
std::vector<Uniform> uniforms
```

that I want to fill using the

```
uniforms.push_back()
```

line. I use this code to do that (the 2nd line is just here to test the copy constructor, as it currently fails)

```
Uniform uni(uniform_name,type);
Uniform uni2=uni;
uniforms.push_back(uni2);
```

The default constructor works fine, the "uni2=uni" compiles without problem (so the default copy constructor is OK too), but the push_back returns (using g++ as a compiler):

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/ext/new_allocator.h:108:9: erreur: no matching function for call to ‘Uniform::Uniform(const Uniform&)’
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/ext/new_allocator.h:108:9: note: candidates are:
>
> ./inc/uniform.h:16:5: note: Uniform::Uniform(std::string, Uniform_Type)
>
> ./inc/uniform.h:16:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
>
> ./inc/uniform.h:14:7: note: Uniform::Uniform(Uniform&)
>
> ./inc/uniform.h:14:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Uniform’ to ‘Uniform&’

Thanks :)

Comment: Firstly, where is the definition of `Uniform`? Secondly, stop abusing the term "default". "Default" has a very specific meaning in C++. "Default constructor" and "copy constructor" are two completely different things in C++. In your case default constructor is not involved at all.

Comment: You should also look at this question, as you have exactly the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302899/using-stdcopy-error-c2679-cant-find-correct-binary-operator/6303073#6303073

Comment: As AndreyT said, please post code (ideally that can be compiled to produce the symptoms described) instead of describing the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you say "default copy constructor" (which generally makes little sense), I assume you mean "implicitly-declared copy constructor" or "compiler-provided copy constructor"

The exact signature of the compiler-provided copy constructor will depend on the contents of your `Uniform` class. It could be `Uniform::Uniform(const Uniform &)` or `Uniform::Uniform(Uniform &)` depending, again, on the details of `Uniform` (which you didn't provide).

For example, if your `Uniform` includes a subobject (base or member) of type `T`, whose copy constructor is declared as `T::T(T &)` (no `const`), then `Uniform`'s implicit constructor will also be implicitly declared as `Uniform::Uniform(Uniform &)` (no `const`).

A full specification can be found in the language standard (12.8/5)

> The implicitly-declared copy
>   constructor for a class X will have
>   the form
>
> `X::X(const X&)`
>
> if
>
> — each
>   direct or virtual base class B of X
>   has a copy constructor whose first
>   parameter is of type const B& or const
>   volatile B&, and
>
> — for all the
>   nonstatic data members of X that are
>   of a class type M (or array thereof),
>   each such class type has a copy
>   constructor whose first parameter is
>   of type const M& or const volatile
>   M&.
>
> Otherwise, the implicitly
>   declared copy constructor will have
>   the form
>
> `X::X(X&)`
>
> An
>   implicitly-declared copy constructor
>   is an inline public member of its
>   class.

The `push_back` implementation needs `Uniform::Uniform(const Uniform &)`, but something in your class causes it to be `Uniform::Uniform(Uniform &)`. Hence the error. There's no way to say what it is without seeing the definition of your `Uniform`.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what sort of thing in `Uniform` might cause the compiler to generate a copy constructor that takes a non-const reference parameter?

Comment: @HighCommander - if the class contains members that have copy constructors that don't have a `const` qualified parameter then the implicitly-declared copy constructor will also not be `const` qualified.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor needs to take its argument as a **const** reference:

```
Uniform::Uniform(const Uniform& other)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor should accept `const Uniform&` and not `Uniform&` as the one you have does.

Answer (score 0):

You failed to include the copy constructor (sic!!!) but you must have defined it wrongly:

```
Uniform::Uniform(Uniform&)
{
     ....
}
```

should be (note the **const**)

```
Uniform::Uniform(const Uniform&)
{
     ....
}
```