# Vector - push_back uses default constructor not copy constructor

Tags: c++, vector, push, back

I'm facing the problem of adding new elements to my vector.
Let's start with the herarchy

Index conatins Companies. Companies contain Stocks

```
Index
{
...
vector <Company> composition;
...
}

Company
{
...
vector <Stock> stocks;
...
}

Stock
{
....
}
```

The problem is when I start adding a company with stocks (till this moment everything is ok) to an index

```
Comapny c1(bla bla, some arguments);
mindex->composition.push_back(c1);
```

Where "mindex" is defined as

```
 Index* mindex=new Index();
```

I got some memory errors and I decided to put some `cout<<"here\n";` in some parts of the program to see what was going on.

While

```
mindex->composition.push_back(c1);
```

is being executed, (at first I sized it `mindex->composition.resize(0);` ) it's size is being enlarged so that everything in it is moved to the temporary vector and in `composition` everything is deleted. But then `vector` uses not copy constructor, but default constructor to create the Stocks.

```
Stock::Stock()
{
  cout<<"The default constructor\n";
}
```

I got this on the screen about 6 times.

The question is: Why vector doesn't use copy contructor when it is being enlarged?
(I have my copy constructor declared and defined)

COMPLETE CODE WHERE THE THING HAPPENS:
Sorry for my language - it's Polish :)

```
Akcja=Stock
Spolka=Company
Indeks=Index

void Portfel<T,T2,T3>::dodaj_spolke()
{
  std::string nazwa;
  double cena_emisji;
  double aktualna_cena;
  usi ilosc_akcji;   
  std::string indeks;
  cout<<"Podaj nazwe spolki: \n";                      //UNIMPORTANT
  cin>>nazwa;
  cout<<"Podaj cene emisji akcji przy IPO. \n";
  cin>>cena_emisji;
  cout<<"Ile akcji jest w obiegu ?\n";
  cin>>ilosc_akcji;
  cout<<"Jaka jest aktualna cena? \n";
  cin>>aktualna_cena;
  if (mindex->GetNast()==NULL)
  {
      cout<<"Spolka zostanie przypisana domyslnie do WIG. \n";
      indeks="WIG";
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"Do jakiego indeksu nalezy spolka? \n";
    cin>>indeks;
  }                                                         //TILL THIS MOMENT
Spolka s1(nazwa,cena_emisji,aktualna_cena,ilosc_akcji,indeks);
cout<<"-------------------------------------------\n";
for (int i=0;i<(int)s1.akcje.size();i++)
{
 cout<<"Spolka: "<<s1.akcje[i].spolka<<endl;
  cout<<"Cena aktualna: "<<s1.akcje[i].cena_aktualna<<endl;
  cout<<"Twoja cena zakupu: "<<s1.akcje[i].cena_zakupu<<endl;
} 
cout<<"-------------------------------------------\n";
cout<<"tutaj po dodaniu spolki \n";
cout<<"Przed zmiana \n"; 
Spolka s2=s1;
mindex->sklad.push_back(Spolka s1); // tutaj błąd
cout<<"Zmiana rozmiaru wektora - tutaj pomiedzy \n";
mindex->ilosc_spolek++;
for (int i=0;i<ilosc_akcji;i++)
{
mindex->sklad[mindex->ilosc_spolek-1].akcje[i].spolka=nazwa;
mindex->sklad[mindex->ilosc_spolek-1].akcje[i].cena_aktualna=aktualna_cena;
Akcja::Akcja()
{
  //std::cout<<sizeof(this)<<std::endl;
  cout<<"Domyslny konstruktor \n";
}
Akcja::Akcja(std::string nazwa,double akt)
{
  spolka=nazwa;
  cena_zakupu=0;
  cena_aktualna=akt;
  zysk=cena_zakupu-cena_aktualna;
}
Akcja::Akcja(const Akcja& a1)
{
  this->spolka=a1.spolka;
  this->cena_zakupu=a1.cena_zakupu;
  this->cena_aktualna=a1.cena_aktualna;
  this->zysk=a1.zysk;
}    mindex->sklad[mindex->ilosc_spolek-1].akcje[i].cena_zakupu=0;
mindex->sklad[mindex->ilosc_spolek-1].akcje[i].zysk=0;

}
cout<<"tutaj koniec\n";
cout<<"Ilosc spolek w mindex: "<<mindex->sklad.size()<<"\n";
cout<<mindex->ilosc_spolek<<endl;
cout<<"-------------------------------------------\n";
for (int i=0;i<mindex->ilosc_spolek;i++)
{
    cout<<mindex->sklad[i].GetNazwa()<<endl;
    cout<<mindex->sklad[i].akcje[0].GetSpolka()<<endl;
    cout<<mindex->sklad[i].akcje[0].cena_zakupu<<endl;
    cout<<mindex->sklad[i].akcje[0].cena_aktualna<<endl;
}
cout<<"-------------------------------------------\n";
getchar();
}
```

spolka.cpp (the concerning part only - there's no need to paste the rest of the code, but I obviously may if you wish)

```
Spolka::Spolka(string naz,double cena_e,double cena_a,usi ilosc,string ind)
{
  nazwa=naz;
  cena_emisji=cena_e;
  aktualna_cena=cena_a;
  ilosc_akcji=ilosc;
  akcje.resize(0);
   for(int i=0;i<ilosc;i++)
   {
    akcje.push_back(Akcja (naz,cena_e));
   }
  indeks=ind;
  std::cout<<"Dodano spolke: "<<this->nazwa<<endl;
}
```

akcja.cpp

```
Akcja::Akcja()
{
  //std::cout<<sizeof(this)<<std::endl;
  cout<<"Domyslny konstruktor \n";
}
Akcja::Akcja(std::string nazwa,double akt)
{
  spolka=nazwa;
  cena_zakupu=0;
  cena_aktualna=akt;
  zysk=cena_zakupu-cena_aktualna;
}
Akcja::Akcja(const Akcja& a1)
{
  this->spolka=a1.spolka;
  this->cena_zakupu=a1.cena_zakupu;
  this->cena_aktualna=a1.cena_aktualna;
  this->zysk=a1.zysk;
}
```

and the effects:

after adding first company

```
    tutaj po dodaniu spolki 
    Przed zmiana 
    Domyslny konstruktor 
    Domyslny konstruktor 
    Domyslny konstruktor 
    Domyslny konstruktor 
    Domyslny konstruktor 
    Domyslny konstruktor 
    Zmiana rozmiaru wektora - tutaj pomiedzy 
    tutaj koniec
    Ilosc spolek w mindex: 1
    1
    -------------------------------------------
    KGHM
    KGHM
    0
    160
    -------------------------------------------
    Usunieto: KGHM
    Usunieto: KGHM

and after adding second company

tutaj po dodaniu spolki 
Przed zmiana 
Domyslny konstruktor 
Domyslny konstruktor 
Domyslny konstruktor 
Domyslny konstruktor 
Domyslny konstruktor 
Domyslny konstruktor 
Domyslny konstruktor 
Domyslny konstruktor 
Domyslny konstruktor 
Usunieto: KGHM
Zmiana rozmiaru wektora - tutaj pomiedzy 
tutaj koniec
Ilosc spolek w mindex: 2
2
-------------------------------------------
KGHM

==2375== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2375==    at 0x539A683: __printf_fp (printf_fp.c:406)
==2375==    by 0x53975B7: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==2375==    by 0x53BF441: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:120)
==2375==    by 0x4EB62DF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==2375==    by 0x4EBC715: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >
```

I know it's much but I would be really grateful for help.

Comment: I think you can find the answer to your question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310638/c-vectorpush-back-using-default-copy-constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
mindmindex->composition.resize(0);
```

Was that really supposed to be `0`? Assuming you resized the vector, `resize` is what calls the default constructor, so that is the reason why you see `The default constructor` 6 times. What you probably wanted is `reserve` and not `resize` which does not call the default constructor.

Comment: At the begining, yes.
Because when program is launched mindex->composition consists of 0 company.
But you know.. I resized the vector at the begining.
Now the problem is with Stocks, not Index

Comment: I can't tell from the code, but whenever you resize a vector, the default constructor is called to initialize the elements. To avoid that, do not resize the vector and call `reserve` instead before pushing back elements onto the vector.

Comment: I FOUND IT
IT WAS IN THE COPY CONSTRUCTOR OF THE SPOLKA.
I made there a line which made default construcotrs :)

Comment: @user1960582: You said `there's no need to paste the rest of the code`, but obviously that was incorrect. Would you like to delete this question?