# Reading a text file line by line, using char* and not string c++

Tags: c++

i have the next code:

```
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream myfile ("text.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
```

is there a way to do it, and use char* instead of string?

Comment: **Why** would you want to do that with `char*`?

Comment: so you want to read the text file char by char? Not getting your point..

Comment: Yes, there is a simple way: `line.c_str()`.

Comment: @Mat -there are function that i would like to use in my code that don't match the string type

Comment: @jack - i dont wont to add the string library at all..

Comment: I have a wife and kids, a great job and a Mercedes. Is there a way to live the same life unemployed, divorced and on the streets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're looking for a more "C-like" solution?

```
#include<cstdio>
#define ENOUGH 1000

int main() {

    char buffer[ENOUGH];

    FILE* f = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    while (true) {
       if (fgets(buffer, ENOUGH, f) == NULL) break;
       puts(buffer);
    }
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

...plus some check whether the file was correctly opened. In this case, you use `fgets()` on the file `f`, reading into the char* `buffer`. However, buffer has only `ENOUGH` space allocated and this limit is also an important parameter to the `fgets()` function. It will stop reading the line when reaching `ENOUGH - 1` characters, so you should make sure the `ENOUGH` constant is large enough.

But if you didn't mean to solve this in a "C-like" way, but are still going to use `<iostream>`, then you probably just want to know that the `c_str()` method of `std::string` returns the `char*` representation of that `std::string`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you really insist. There's a version of `getline` that's a member of `std::istream` that will do it:

```
char buffer[1024];

std::ifstream myfile("text.txt");

while (myfile.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer))
    std::cout << buffer << "\n";
myfile.close();
```

Note, however, that most C++ programmers would consider this obsolescent at best. Oh, and for the record, the loop in your question isn't really correct either. Using string, you'd typically want something like:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream myfile("text.txt");

while (std::getline(myfile, line))
    std::cout << line << "\n";
myfile.close();
```

or, you could use the `line` proxy from one of [my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567703/179910), in which case it becomes simpler still:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<line>(myfile),
          std::istream_iterator<line>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```