# c++ basic string manipulation

Tags: java, c++, string

There's a simple string manipulation problem where you are required to reverse the words of each line: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=121&page=show_problem&problem=424

So:

```
I love you.
You love me.
We're a happy family.
```

Would become:

```
I evol .uoy
uoY evol .em
er'eW a yppah .ylimaf
```

Now, I've written a simple java solution which looks something like:

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s;
while((s=file.readLine())!=null){
    String[] sr = s.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i<sr.length; i++)
        System.out.print(new StringBuffer(sr[i]).reverse() + (i==sr.length-1?"\n":" "));
}
```

Because I am trying to learn c++, I've also tried writing a c++ solution which looks like:

```
string s;
while(getline(cin, s)){
    string tmp = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<=s.length(); i++)
        if( i==s.length() || s[i] == ' '){
            for(int j = tmp.length(); j>=0; j--)
                cout << tmp[j];
            if( i == s.length()) cout << endl;
            else cout << " ";
            tmp = "";
        }else
            tmp += s[i];
}
```

My questions are:

1. The c++ solution returns "wrong answer", whereas the java one is accepted, why?
2. What improvements, if any, can be made to the c++ solution?

Comment: Just so you don't ever actually *use* this for anything (possibly recreating it again), `std::reverse`.

Comment: what kind of output are you seeing when you test it?

Comment: I see the java and the c code but no C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string line_string;
while ( getline( std::cin, line_string ) ) {

    // Instead of `split`, read out of a std::istringstream:
    std::istringstream line_stream( line_string );
    std::string word;
    while ( line_stream >> word ) {

        // Use std::reverse instead of a loop:
        std::reverse( word.begin(), word.end() );

        // Always qualify with std:: instead of using namespace std;
        std::cout << word << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n'; // prefer '\n' to std::endl unless you need a flush
}
```

http://ideone.com/hd3bg

If this doesn't pass, it's probably because of the trailing space at the end of each line. Use a Boolean variable to avoid printing space before newline.

Comment: There are ways other than a boolean. I particularly like Jerry's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c). It may be longer than what you might need once, but it's designed quite well to use more than once. The pre-made, versatile, reusable stuff comes in handy when you want a quick solution.

Comment: @chris: Wow, that's a bit heavy duty. Actually the standard library has a similar idiom in `std::ostream_iterator`, I'll adjust this answer.

Comment: That's true, I forgot about that one. The infix has the advantage of working for other uses like copying data around, but the `ostream_iterator` works well for printing.

Comment: @chris: woops, I was wrong, `ostream_iterator` implements a delimiter but stupidly prints it unconditionally :v(

Comment: Does it really? I still would've expected that to pass through the usefulness test.

Answer (score 3):

If boost is allowed, I would use a combination of [`boost::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id820181.html), [`boost::join`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/join.html) and [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

```
std::string line;
std::vector<std::string> vs;
while (getline(std::cin, line)) {       
    boost::split(vs, line, ::isspace);
    for (auto & word : vs)
        std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
    std::cout << boost::join(vs, " ") << '\n';
}
```

If boost is not available, I would have those functions (or similar) in my personal library and I would just copy them into my submission.

Comment: I don't think `boost` library is allowed on the online judge. This is probably good as a general answer, though.

Comment: The fact that Boost probably won't be on an online judge is the reason this answer *isn't* general. It's nice to know about, though.

Answer (score 1):

the reason of wrong is:

```
string s;
while(getline(cin, s)){
    string tmp = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<=s.length(); i++)
        if( i==s.length() || s[i] == ' '){
            for(int j = tmp.length(); j>=0; j--)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ => the first tmp[j] is \0!
                                     => should be tmp.length()-1
                cout << tmp[j];
            if( i == s.length()) cout << endl;
            else cout << " ";
            tmp = "";
        }else
            tmp += s[i];
}
```

remember, in c/c++, an index starts from 0.

Comment: Sorry but did you check the output of tmp[0] ? In C++ a string has length so it doesn't end with '\0'

Comment: @lollancf37: Actually in C++11 (and in practice it's true in C++03 too) `std::string` _does_ end in '\0', it's just not counted in its length, see 21.4.5/2 and 21.4.7/1.

Comment: @JonathanWakely thanks. However I still don't think that the issue brought here doesn't apply.

Comment: @JonathanWakely in c/c++/c++11, all string length don't count the ending \0. However, tmp[length()] points to the \0 or something else if not \0. for c++11 21.4.7.1, c_str()[size()] is valid, so you can guarantee there is a \0 in the end still.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutly want to create a new variable to handle the reverse operation instead of simple printing in the reverse order. Then you have to take in consideration the fallowing :
In C++ the index is not the length of a string. Because the index starts at 0, so you start from the index 0 to the index : length - 1

If you want to start C++, after you're familiar with the basics it's always good to digg into the STL before going anywhere else (that's just my opinion).

Here is some code :

```
string s;  
while(getline(cin, s))
{      
   string tmp = "";      
   for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i++)
       std::cout<<s[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if I was going to do this, I'd reverse each word by constructing a new string, passing `word.rbegin(), word.rend()` as the arguments to the constructor.

Using the [`Line` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567703/179910) from one of my previous answers, and the [`infix_ostream_iterator`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3497021/179910) from another, it could look something like this:

```
#include "infix_iterator.h"
#include "line"


int main() {
    auto rev_words = [](std::string const &in) -> std::string {
        std::istringstream b(in);
        std::ostringstream r;

        std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(b),
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
            infix_ostream_iterator<std::string>(r, " "),
            [](std::string const &in){return std::string(in.rbegin(), 
                                                         in.rend());});
        return r.str();
    };

    std::transform(std::istream_iterator<line>(std::cin), 
        std::istream_iterator<line>(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
        rev_words);
    return 0;
}
```

Yes, this is probably going a bit overboard on fully-functional style. It's undoubtedly easier to do something like this instead:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::istringstream buffer(line);
    std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer),
                   std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                   infix_ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout , " "), 
                   [](std::string const &in){return std::string(in.rbegin(), 
                                                                in.rend()););
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the one i tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

 using namespace std;


 int main(){

    string s = "Hello How are you Mr vins what are you doing now";
    string temp, reverse;

   int i,j;
     // Traverse through First string
    for (i=0;i <=s.length(); i++)
   {
if(s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\0') {
    //After getting space reverse the previous word and add to reverse string
    for (j = temp.length(); j >=0; j--)
        reverse = reverse + temp[j];

    reverse = reverse + " ";
    temp="";
    continue;
}
temp = temp + s[i];

}

 cout << "\nlets see reversed sentence \n";

   cout << reverse << "\n";
      return 0;
   }
```