# iterate through lines in a string c++

Tags: c++, string, join, split

here's what I need to do.  I have a string in C++.  For every line in the string, I need to append a few characters (like ">> ") to the beginning of the line.  What I am struggling with is a good way to split the string around newlines, iterate through the elements appending the characters, and then rejoin the string together.  I've seen a few ideas, such as `strtok()`, but I was hoping c++ strings would have something a little more elegant.

Comment: Hope this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c could help

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a straight-forward solution. Maybe not the most efficient, but unless this is hot code or the string is huge, it should do fine. We suppose that your input string is called `input`:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string result;

std::istringstream iss(input);

for (std::string line; std::getline(iss, line); )
{
    result += ">> " + line + "\n";
}

// now use "result"
```

Answer (score 5):

A more functional approach would be to use a `getline`-based iterator as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567703/91757) and then use that with [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for transforming all input lines, like this:

```
std::string transmogrify( const std::string &s ) {
    struct Local {
        static std::string indentLine( const std::string &s ) {
            return ">> " + s;
        }
    };

    std::istringstream input( s );
    std::ostringstream output;
    std::transform( std::istream_iterator<line>( input ), 
                    std::istream_iterator<line>(),
                    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( output, "\n" ),
                    Local::indentLine );
    return output.str();
}
```

The `indentLine` helper actually indents the line, the newlines are inserted by the `ostream_iterator`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Right, I adjusted the wording.

Answer (score 3):

If the data in your string is basically like a file, try using [`std::stringstream`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
std::istringstream lines( string_of_lines );
std::ostringstream indented_lines;
std::string one_line;
while ( getline( lines, one_line ) ) {
    indented_lines << ">> " << one_line << '\n';
}
std::cout << indented_lines.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a `stringstream` and use `std::getline` to extract a line at a time:

```
std::string transmogrify(std::string const & in) {
    std::istringstream ss(in);
    std::string line, out;
    while (getline(ss, line)) {
        out += ">> ";
        out += line;
        out += '\n';
    }
    return out;
}
```