# Creating a big size array of type char and copying file characters

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, fstream

I have to copy characters of a file in a big size array, so I created this code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > strings;

strings.resize(rows);

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)  
{ 
    strings[i].resize(columns); 
}

ifstream in("filename.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)    
    in.getline(strings[i], columns);
```

`strings` should contain all the characters of the file, but when I compile this program, I have the following error:

> no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream >::getline(std::vector >&, int)’

(and others error lines)

How can I copy all characters of a file in a big char array?

Comment: *I have to copy characters of a file in a big size array* - what makes you think you have to? Is there really no way to parse the file content on the fly?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1567082/179910

Comment: I have to read first 6 elements of every line, so someone suggest me to copy all file in a 2-dimensional array

Comment: IF you have to read the first 6 elements per line, then read the first 6 elements of one line, use them and go on to the next line, instead of copying the whole stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`in.getline()` cannot take a vector of `char` as its first argument. You should use `std::string`.

You could do `getline(in, strings[i]);`.

To fill in values for a 2d vector, you could do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    in >> strings[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: array rows represent file lines, array columns represents every character in the line

Comment: With this change I have the following error: "cannot convert ‘std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >’ to ‘size_t*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’"

Comment: Don't use a `vector<char>`, use `vector<string>`. Also, which change did you make?

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYBODY, I SOLVED IT

Answer (score 0):

you should use `std::string`instread of `std::vector<char>`

if for some reason you really need to use the data structure `std::vector<std::vector<char> >`

then use `std::string` to read the file and then convert it to `std::vector<char>` but i don't see why you would want to do that

Answer (score 0):

As OGH recommends, I would use `std::vector<std::string> strings;` instead of `vector<vector<char>> strings;` and qork with string header's getline:

`getline(in, strings[i]);`