# C++ hasNextLine

Tags: java, c++, file-io, input

I have something done very easily in Java, but what is the C++ version of the following:

```
while (in.hasNextLine())
{                
     String line = in.nextLine();

     if (i == 13)
     {
         i++;
         break;                    
     }  

     i++;
}
```

It's the nextLine parts I can't seem to find a C++ equivalent for

Comment: what is the object in ?

Comment: This is basically an exact dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1567082/179910, except for basic differences in how iterators work in C++.

Comment: is `in` a file stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::ifstream in("Path\\To\\File.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(in, line))
{
    if (i++ == 13)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `in` is a file stream

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>    
while (std::getline(in, line))
{

       // Do your thing 
}
```