# C++ - getline stdin EOF not working

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm new to C++ and I'm working on a basic C++ project.

I have some lines of text (with whitespace in them) that I want to make the program accept from standard input and then stop when it encounters a (simulated) EOF because of a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

I've looked up and tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800535/c-hasnextline) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742551/read-strings-from-input-till-eof). They work ie the code in the while loop stops executing after I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> but for some reason the following lines of code do not get executed.

I've tried various ways to do this but I keep getting the same problem.

```
string line;
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    if (getline(cin, line)) {
        A[i] = line;
        cout << A[i] << endl; //executes as expected
        i++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
cout << "exited" << endl; //not executed even after ctrl+d
```

Here's another method I tried:

```
string line;
int i = 0;
while (getline(cin, line)){
    //cin.ignore();
    A[i] = line;
    cout << A[i] << endl; //executes as expected
    i++;

}
cout << "exited" << endl; //still not executed
```

---

Sample input:

```
DUCHESS 26
MARIE 8
BERLIOZ 8
TOULOUSE 7
THOMAS 28
```

---

PS: I use Eclipse CDT on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: This question was posted in May 2015, bug still exists in Eclipse Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known eclipse bug.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159803

Have you tried it in the Terminal?