# c++: Foreach line in string (not file)

Tags: c++, loops, foreach, newline

In c++, how can I iterate through each line in a **string**? There have been plenty of questions regarding reading a file line by line, but how can I do this with a `std::string`?

For example, if I have the following string:

```
1051
2232
5152
3821
0021
3258
```

How would I iterate through each number?

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't think it's the same, I'm not using `cin` and I don't want to read anything into a `std::string`.

Comment: @ChristianStewart: Sorry, I mis-read -- didn't understand that the string is your source instead of destination. In this case, `stringstream` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c++, you can use string exactly as files, using the classes defined in the `sstream` header:

```
#include <sstream>
//...
std::string str=...; // your string
std::istrstream in(str); // an istream, just like ifstream and cin
std::string line;
while(std::getline(in,line)){
  //do stuff with line
}
```

This is a bit simplistic, but you get the idea.

You can use `in` just as you would use `cin`, e.g. `in>>x` etc. Hence the solutions from [How do I iterate over cin line by line in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c) are relevant here too - you might want to look at them for the "real" answer (just replace `cin` with your own `istream`

Edit:
As a side note, you can create strings in the same way you print to the screen, using the `ostream` mechanism (like `cout`):

```
std::ostringstream out;
out << header << "_" << 3.5<<".txt";
std::string filename=out.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a tokenizer and let '\n' or '\r\n' or the appropriate newline for your OS be the token splitter..

Or if you were using a buffered file stream reader, just create a stringstream from this new string and read from the string stream instead of the file stream.

In short nothing changes except that you aren't reading from a file.

A horribly naive solution would be to make a string stream from this and assign ints or strings in a while loop from it.

Comment: @cluracan just wrote the code to do exactly what I described in part 2