# Convert a list (.txt file) into an array form

Tags: c++

Say that I have a .txt file with 5000 words one above the other. and I want to convert that list contained in the txt file into this form:

{"word1, "word2", "word3" ....."word5000"}

So that way I can use it as an array for C++.

Is there a way to do that? Any method is welcome , as long as it is an automated process. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  This question is too broad in scope.  If you are beginning C++, maybe read some tutorials on file i/o and data structures and standard library collections.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector instead of an array. Using it, the task looks something like this:

```
std::ifstream in("words.txt");

std::vector<std::string> words{ std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                                std::istream_iterator<std::string>() };
```

Now the word that was on the first line of the file is in `words[0]`, the second in `words[1]`, and so on.

Note: if a line contains more than one word, this will read them as separate words. If you want the entire contents of a line treated as a single word, see the answers to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1567082/179910) specifically about how to do that.