# Looking to disclude lines from std::count parameters

Tags: c++, count, line, std

Currently using:

```
{
std::ifstream inFile("test.txt");
int x = std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n');

cout<<x<<endl;
}
```

Though, I'm looking to disclude lines starting with comments (I.E. '//'), thoughts?
Or, would I need to write this with something else completely?

EDIT::

I wound up going a different route entirely so that I would be capable of counting all lines of all files in the current working directory.

Comment: Probably `std::accumulate` with line-based iterators and counting within the accumulator function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to read the file line by line. There's a nice way of doing it through a [`std::string` proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567703/19093). Second, you need to use `std::count_if` so that you can pass a predicate which will determine whether the line starts with the comment sequence or not.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>

class line
{
  std::string data;

public:
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, line& l)
  {
    std::getline(is, l.data);
    return is;
  }

  operator std::string() const
  {
    return data;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::ifstream file("./test.txt");

  auto count = std::count_if(std::istream_iterator<line>(file),
                             std::istream_iterator<line>(), [](const line& l) {
    return !boost::algorithm::starts_with(static_cast<std::string>(l), "//");
  });

  std::cout << count << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a filtering streambuf that discards lines beginning with `//`. The stream should wrap around the file buffer of `inFile`. James Kanze does something similar in his [article](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/att-49459/fltrsbf1.htm):

Answer (score 0):

I would think iterating over the lines and use a predicate function would be the way