# Parsing a .csv file consisting numbers with characters in between (C++)

Tags: c++, csv, parsing

I have a file that looks like this

```
=sjkc(11,32as%2dc 32,43)a-b,49,26),b.'47,28n,a=64  and so on...
```

The objective is to retrieve all the Digits while ignoring any other characters in between. There is no newline so the coordinates are just continuous throughout the file.

Note: Not allowed to use regex and map

So for this instance, it should return the number 11 then 32 then 2 then 32 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking for CSV parsing — you ignore field boundaries — you just want to extract all numbers from a string.

Do that by replacing everything that is not a number with spaces, then using a stringstream to extract.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s = "=sjkc(11,32as%2dc 32,43)a-b,49,26),b.'47,28n,a=64";

  std::transform( s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), []( char c ) 
  { 
    return std::isdigit( c ) ? c : ' ';
  } );

  std::istringstream ss( s );
  int n;
  while (ss >> n)
    std::cout << n << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Jerry Coffin for his nifty example in this answer: [How do I iterate over cin line by line in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c/1567703#1567703)

It led to this:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct digit_reader : std::ctype<char>
{
    digit_reader() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}
    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask>
            rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());

        for (size_t i = 0; i < table_size; ++i)
        {
            rc[i] = std::isdigit(i) ? std::ctype_base::digit : std::ctype_base::space;
        }
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("=sjkc(11,32as%2dc 32,43)a-b,49,26),b.'47,28n,a=64");
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new digit_reader()));

    int num;
    while (ss >> num)
    {
        std::cout << num << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You should be able to imbue any input stream, like std::cin or a std::ifstream, with this facet and skip everything but numbers.